# Replace two 15amp breakers for one 30amp subpanel

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel

I’ve searched a bit and I don’t know if this has been asked or attempted but…

Basically I want to run a few commercial grade pieces of equipment that have 240v plugs. My current situation is this:

100Amp main
15amp breaker that powers some receptacles in the kitchen and one in the garage.
15 breaker that powers a jet tub from the previous owners.

I don’t use the jet tub ever so I’m wondering if I can take out the two 15 amp breakers and replace them for one 30amp two pole breaker which then runs to a sub-panel.

On this sub-panel can I then put the receptacles that were on the previous 15 breaker in the main panel in this new sub panel on a 120v 15amp breaker. And then run a 240v 15amp breaker to a 240v outlet in my garage

Comment: You will need to also change the wires/cable to the sub panel to minimum of 10 gauge copper or 8 gauge aluminum.  You also need to see if the equipment only needs 15 amps or more.

Comment: A) Yes, there are dozens of questions here about upgrading a circuit to a larger breaker. B) Pictures of the two panels with the covers off will be most helpful. C) reread crip659's note above about wire size!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds good.

But whenever people go for a new panel we always suggest going big, get a lot of spaces to avoid the exact issue you are having now. The cost difference now is minimal compared to doing all this work again.

If the distance between the main and subpanel is short then go big for the feed to the subpanel as well (go for a 100+ Amp panel and feed instead of a dinky 30A one) so you aren't juggling capacity of the new panel, the upcharge for the few feet worth of thicker wire (especially when you pick aluminum) isn't that much.

Don't eliminate the existing 15A circuit entirely, a 120V outlet is far too useful to simply delete it if it's not in the way.

Also if you are running new circuits to your garage consider making preparations for adding a circuit for an EV charger, even if you are not putting one in right now.